# Does the every reference have symbol entry

Tags: linker

Now I'm reading computer systems : a programmer's perspective, and in the chapter 7 Linking.
There are reference, symbol and entry related knowledge, what mentioned in book is Entry has definition of symbol, and my thought about these is "Every symbol has entry, and entry has symbol reference like pointer, this reference actually has some address".
Therefore, every time I read code related global variable or function / procedure, all of them actually can be regarded as corresponding entry, which has symbol reference and other info.

Finally, my thought is right? can I keep going with this thought? Really want to understand all about computer system and techniques related programming.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRdfs.png)

Oh~final question, is the symbol table in .symtab section same with relocation entry table?

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid associating *symbol* with *entry*. The term **entry** is reserved in most linkers to specify the *entry point* of the whole linked program, i.e. address of the first instruction performed at the start of program execution. I prefer the term **records** for items arranged into table, for instance the **symbol table**.

When you create a procedure or function in your program, it will be loaded at certain address in memory when the program runs. You don't know where exactly (at which numeric address) will the procedure be located at run-time, that's why you give that address a symbolic name (label). That is **symbol** - a human-readable denomination of certain position in program (address symbol) or of a constant value (scalar symbol).
You can call the procedure or refer to it at write-time using its symbolic name: `CALL MyProcedure` or
`MOV register,MyProcedure`. Again, the final value of MyProcedure address is not known yet, so compiler temporarily puts 0 into the instruction body instead of this address, and creates a relocation record in **relocation table**. Each such record specifies **1)** pointer to the temporary 0 inside the instruction body, and
**2)** specification of the target symbol in the form of index into symbol table.
Global symbols, such as `MyProcedure` should be unique in the program, but they may be referred many times, and each reference will create a record in relocation table.
The relation between symbol and relocation is not 1:1.

When the linker has enough information to decide about the final address of each symbol, it will go through relocation table and replace temporary 0 in the code with symbol's final address.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer, it's very helpful for me.https://drive.google.com/file/d/10yquVWxp5kc-7VQUngJik7TlUACgcPBS/view Here is arranged knowledge related this question topic. Now I know the relationship between the symbol in the code and symbol table, also what entry actually meaning is like a address.Thank you again~